# Ohm symbol not showing in math mode using custom beamer styling

Tags: beamer, symbols, siunitx, typography

So, I'm using a custom beamer styling required by my employer, and while trying to typeset some problem examples with the "ohm" symbol, I've noticed it doesn't always work.

At first, I noticed it didn't appear at all, using the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible} \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \usecolortheme[RGB={122,4,24}]{structure}
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,output-decimal-marker={,},math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ,exponent-product = \cdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Sumário}

\begin{frame}{Sumário}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
    You can see that this doesn't work: \SI{1}{\ohm}

    Nor does this: $ \SI{1}{\ohm} $

    Or this: $$ \SI{1}{\ohm} $$
    Or this: \[ \SI{1}{\ohm} \]
    Or \[ \text{\SI{1}{\ohm}} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After adding `detect-all=true` to the `\sisetup` command I managed to get the `\SI` macros in text-mode to work, but none of the math ones, like so.

[image]

I noticed that if I remove the `\usefonttheme{serif}` line from the styling definition (idk how to call it, sorry), everything works as usual.

[image: Literally same code, but with the font theme 'serif' line commented]

I thought of redefining the Omega characters used by the siunitx package, but to no avail.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}
```

Also tried to change the font used by the package (`math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\rmfamily` in `\sisetup`), and to make it insensitive to outside family font (`detect-family=false` in `\sisetup`). All without any clear result.

Comment: Are you forced to use the `polyglossia` package? Things seem to work just fine if I replace `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}` with `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}`, under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Well, actually, I'm not. Thank you, @Mico. Hadn't thought of it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Done! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much looks like the issue you've come across is a (bad) side-effect of using the `polyglossia` package, which seems to have a few issues when used with the `brazil` language option.

Unless you absolutely must use the `polyglossia` package, an easy remedy consists of (a) getting rid of (or, at least, commenting out) the instructions

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}
```

and (b) running, in their place, the instruction

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
```

A separate comment/observation: I would also get rid of the `siunitx` options `math-micro=\text{µ}` and `text-micro=µ`. For sure, when used in tandem with the `babel` package, these options generate incorrect output when writing, say, `\si{\micro\ohm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible} \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \usecolortheme[RGB={122,4,24}]{structure}
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,output-decimal-marker={,},exponent-product = \cdot}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    This works now: \SI{1}{\micro\ohm}

    So does this: $\SI{1}{\micro\ohm}$

    And this: $$ \SI{1}{\micro\ohm} $$
    And this: \[ \SI{1}{\micro\ohm} \]
    And this: \[ \text{\SI{1}{\micro\ohm}} \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \setbeamercovered{invisible} \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \usecolortheme[RGB={122,4,24}]{structure}
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{brazil}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  math-micro=\text{µ},
  text-micro=µ,
  exponent-product = \cdot
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
    You can see that this doesn't work: \SI{1}{\ohm}

    Nor does this: $ \SI{1}{\ohm} $

    Or this: \[ \SI{1}{\ohm} \]
    Or \[ \text{\SI{1}{\ohm}} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg! Can you please explain why one shouldn't use the `lmodern` and `fontenc` (with the option `T1`) packages? It is a general practice? I use this everywhere and hadn't any issues till I came to this case described in the question, but with `babel`, `ngerman` and `pdflatex`. Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 The recommendation is for the OP who uses XeLaTeX.

Comment: Hello @egreg! Thank you for the explanation! In my case the ohm symbol wasn't show too, till I removed `lmodern` and `fontenc`. That is why I asking. So, there are somewhere unsupported glyphs?